# Error 0xc00e0003 in MSMQ + WCF inside a Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, msmq

I am hosting a WCF Service, that uses MSMQ, inside a Windows Service.

**Problem:**

After installing the service, I am unable to start the service. Event log has following information:

Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error opening the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running, the queue exists and has proper authorization to be read from.

> The inner exception may contain additional information. ---> 
>   System.ServiceModel.MsmqException: An error occurred while opening the
>   queue:Unrecognized error -1072824317 (0xc00e0003). The message cannot
>   be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and
>   running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open with the
>   required access mode and authorization. at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.OpenQueue() at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.GetHandle() at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.SupportsAccessMode(String
>   formatName, Int32 accessType, MsmqException& msmqException) --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqVerifier.VerifyReceiver(MsmqReceiveParameters
>   receiveParameters, Uri listenUri) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqTransport...

**Note:**

1. The windows service *can* create the queue, but cannot open it for read/write.
2. The windows service is running under **LocalSystem** privilege.
3. `SYSTEM` has full access permissions on the queue.

**Research**

1. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says:

> MQ_ERROR_QUEUE_NOT_FOUND (0xC00E0003)
>
> Returned when Message Queuing cannot find the queue. Such queues
>   include public queues not registered in the directory service and
>   Internet queues that do not exist in the MSMQ namespace. This error is
>   also returned when the user does not have sufficient permissions to
>   perform the operation.

This is impossible, as the queue DOES exist (its creating it in the previous line of code) and has all the permissions.

2. Visited all sites in first page of [Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr#q=0xC00E0003+msmq). Tried all, and the same exception.

**My App.Config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821"/>
  </configSections>
  <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="D:\\FTPFileUpload.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="0"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO"/>
        <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="QueueName" value=".\private$\ftpuploader"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All"/>
    <services>
      <service name="FTPUploader.Core.FtpUpload" behaviorConfiguration="msmqBehavior">
        <endpoint name="msmq" address="MsmqWcfFtpUpload" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="msmqFileUploader" contract="FTPUploader.Contracts.IFtpUpload"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.msmq://localhost/private"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9271"/> <!-- Hardy-Ramanujan's Number, Reversed!-->
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="msmqFileUploader" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="msmqBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution to the problem.

The problem was the word "localhost" which does not work properly with Active Directory system. So you have to explicitly state your machine name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821"/>
  </configSections>
  <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="D:\\FTPFileUpload.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="0"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO"/>
        <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="QueueName" value=".\private$\ftpuploader"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All"/>
    <services>
      <service name="FTPUploader.Core.FtpUpload" behaviorConfiguration="msmqBehavior">
        <endpoint name="msmq" address="MsmqWcfFtpUpload" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="msmqFileUploader" contract="FTPUploader.Contracts.IFtpUpload"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.msmq://MachineName/private"/> <!-- MachineName instead of localhost -->
            <add baseAddress="http://MachineName:9271"/> <!-- Hardy-Ramanujan's Number, Reversed!--> <!-- MachineName instead of localhost -->
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="msmqFileUploader" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="msmqBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```